# Can I use aliases in YAML block scalar?

Tags: yaml, alias, multiline

I would like to inject a YAML field value in a block scalar.
I thought it was possible to reference aliases like so:

```yaml
exclamationMark: &exclamationMark "!"
questionMark: &questionMark "?"
text: |-
   Hi *exclamationMark
   What's your name *questionMark
```

Then get the following JSON output:

```json
{
  "exclamationMark": "!",
  "questionMark": "?",
  "text": "Hi !\nWhat's your name ?"
}
```

But obviously aliases are not interpreted as such and I get this JSON output instead:

```json
{
  "exclamationMark": "!",
  "questionMark": "?",
  "text": "Hi *exclamationMark\nWhat's your name *questionMark"
}
```

Is there a trick or aliases are definitively not supported in block scalars?

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do specifically with block scalars, YAML simply is not a programming language and doesn't support features like string concatenation or interpolation.

YAML describes a directed graph of nodes. Each node may have an anchor, and if so, may be referenced via an alias. A scalar node, which a block scalar (and other scalar syntaxes) is parsed into, contains *scalar content*. Scalar content is textual and will never contain references to other nodes.

Nodes referencing other nodes are *collection nodes*, namely sequences which contain a list of references to other nodes, and mappings, which contain a list of key-value pairs where both key and value are a node reference.

Thus, what you *can* do is

```yaml
exclamationMark: &exclamationMark "!"
questionMark: &questionMark "?"
text: !concat ["Hi ", *exclamationMark, "\nWhat's your name ", *questionMark]
```

This makes the `text` be a sequence of scalars, some being given literally and others via aliases. `!concat` is a local tag and may be processed by the code loading the YAML. This potentially allows you to implement your desired semantics, though you need to write that code yourself.

Comment: Thank you @flyx, that's the answer I was expecting I guess.